# Can we prevent classes implementing an interface in C#?

Tags: c#

I want to create a list of my base interface so I can have polymorphism but I only want classes to inherit from the interfaces that are derived from the base interface - is it possible to seal the base interface so it can only be inherited from other interfaces?

This is what my setup is like:

```
// want to seal this so classes cannot implement it directly
public interface IObject {
    Vector3 Position {get;}
}

public interface IItem : IObject {
    // stuff
}
public interface IWeapon : IObject{
   // stuff
}
```

Then using a collection:

```
List<IObject> _list = new(); // all objects
```

What I am trying to prevent is this:

```
public class MyClass : IObject {}
```

But still allow `IWeapon` and `IItem` to be implemented. Is this a supported feature in C#?

Comment: No, you can't. But really, why is it such a problem for a class to directly implement this interface?

Comment: Closets would be to make IObject internal, but that brings up a dozens other problems. So in short: Not possible.

Comment: You could do this with an abstract class and a private constructor, but that's not quite the same thing

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel its mainly just for abstraction to prevent accidently adding such a class to the list, I'll have to add some logic checks before hand instead in a function before adding to get around it. But it would have been nice if the feature existed though, less typing in the end. Also just enforces a stricter design since it would give a compile error. I stricter design like that :)

Comment: This is a procedural question where you have to make the effort to not implement it. And really this isn't the worst problem to have and if you have that interface as a method arg/dependency all you'll be able to do with it is what it is so it wouldn't create an error unless somewhere else along the line you applied some other code. My suggestion: leave a note in the interface file that it isn't meant to be implemented itself.

Comment: You can write a Roslyn analyzer that will check this.